# How to inject primitive values into a spring bean when created using "new"

Tags: java, spring, object, dependency-injection, primitive

I have an instance of a business-class which is created at runtime (using "new"). I want to inject primitive property values into this entity.
I cannot use @autowired, for I do not want to inject beans, but primitive properties.
I am aware that since the class is not initialized by the Bean Factory itself I need some sort of trick to inject the values anyway. 
So I came along using AspectJ:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

But apparently this does not seem to apply for my problem as is states:
[...] then Spring will validate after configuration that all properties (which are not primitives or collections) have been set. [...]

I want to avoid requesting my object directly from the spring-context. It appears a violation of the DI thought. I mean the point is not to actively call something, but to passively get all dependencies injected, right?

So what can I do to have the primitives injected?

EDIT: Or is it rather because it is uncommon to inject dependencies besides service-beans into business classes?

Comment: Use a constructor with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look to the @Configurable annotation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

Then to inject a value, use @Value, example : @Value("${some.property:defaultvalue}")

The primitive exclusion doesn't seem to affect the @Value annotation. "it is preferable to specify explicit, annotation-driven dependency injection for your @Configurable beans by using @Autowired or @Inject at the field or method level" And @Autowired and @Value are processed by the same beanpostprocessor (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.2.3/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java)

Comment: Your link appears to be almost the same page as I referenced in the original post. I tried that but did not succeed because apparently this technique is not applicable for primitives (search for "primitives" in your page or see quote from the original post).

Comment: The primitive exclusion doesn't seem to affect the @Value annotation.

Comment: You are right! It perfectly works once you set up the project correctly - my bad. ;-)
My problem was, I missed out some aspectj related imports and in particular overlooked launching the application with the right runtime arguments. This is where I found a good walkthrough:
http://tamasgyorfi.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/spring-dependency-injection-configurable/
http://olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/
By the way careful with Java-8 and aspectj - I needed aspectj-1.8.2 to have it work (earlier versions did not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the applicationContext.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${my.property}")

Comment: Yes, I could, but then I would actively call a Spring element to get my values. Which is what I want to avoid if possible, because I want to rely on DI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand because once you say you don't want the business objects Autowired or to use getBean they're no longer managed by the spring container at all.

But your idea of using AspectJ is a good one.  Spring and AspectJ can work together, i.e. AOP, but they don't have to.  I believe you can write a Constructor pointcut and get what you want. [This link should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338788/aspectj-pointcut-on-constructor-object) I've never done a constructor joinpoint and always prefer annotations but it should be a starting point.

Comment: Yes and no. I do want them autowired. But I cannot use the anotation "@autowired", because "@autowired" does only work for injecting other beans, not primitive values defined as properties.

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose these primitives are different each time the object is instantiated? I wonder if you could use a Configuration class, SCOPE_PROTOTYPE on the Component of course, and setters? Maybe snake the values through a properties object similar to how the XML version does constructor-args?    It also matters a whole lot if this is a multi-threaded application or not.  I can't help but think your problem isn't just primitives; that could be solved with Integer,Long,etc  I feel like I'm just guessing at this point. I don't think I fully understand the use case.

Comment: Yes, that was a helpful hint. I guess the contradiction is that on the one hand I want DI, on the other I do not want to have the class instatiated and maintained by the bean factory.

Comment: Eventually I decided to use a properties-file to store the values for the primitives. That file I can access programatically.
The longer I think about it the more I guess primitive injection is intended for spring maintained service-classes, only - and not for business classes.